# undefined-reference Error when defining a function in the *.cpp instead of in the *.h

Tags: c++, qt, class, undefined-reference

I have got a problem: I have 2 classes: **mainwindow** and **ErgebnisAusFortran** which look like this:

mainwindow.h:

```
    #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
    #define MAINWINDOW_H   
    #include <QMainWindow>
    #include <QDebug>
    #include <QString>
    #include "ErgbnisAusFortran.h"        

    namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
    }

    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();        

    public:
        ErgbnisAusFortran Berechnung();        
        ErgbnisAusFortran Berechnung_1()
        {
           ErgbnisAusFortran ret;
           qDebug() << " ich berechne Berechnung_1..." ;               
           return ret;
        }

    private slots:
        void on_pb_Calculate_clicked();      

    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    };

    #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "ErgbnisAusFortran.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pb_Calculate_clicked()
{
     ErgbnisAusFortran Ergebnis_1;
     ErgbnisAusFortran Ergebnis;
     Ergebnis_1 = Berechnung_1();
     Ergebnis = Berechnung();
}

ErgbnisAusFortran Berechnung()
{
    ErgbnisAusFortran ret;
    qDebug() << " ich berechne..." ;
    return ret;
}
```

The thing that puzzles me is the following:

I have 2 methods Berechnung() and Berechnung_1().

Berechnung()   is **declared** in mainwindow.h   and **defined** in mainwindow.cpp

Berechnung_1() is **declared** in mainwindow.h   and **defined** in mainwindow.h

When I run the program i get the following error concerning Berechnung():

undefined reference to MainWindow::Berechnung().Berechnung_1 works well. This puzzles me because I include mainwindow.h in mainwindow.cpp.

Does anybody know what is wrong?

thank you

itelly

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to qualify the name of the member function:

```
ErgbnisAusFortran MainWindow::Berechnung()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

so instead this declared a new non-member function, leaving the member function undefined.